# adding external url jar as an sbt unmanaged dependency

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I am working on an sbt project and I need to pull a jar, available via url, into my project as an unmanaged dependency.

As an example:

- I want to retrieve a jar file available at 
  http://www.sourceGorge.net/fooProject/v4.2/lib/bar.jar.  If the jar file is absent from myProject/lib then simply download the source jar, do nothing otherwise.

One [possible solution](http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/06/sbt-use-jar-file-for-librarydependencies.html) I found on the web suggests the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sf.proguard" % "proguard-base" % "5.0"  
              from "file:///tmp/proguard5.0beta2/lib/proguard.jar"
```

But my question would then be: what am I supposed to substitute for "net.sf.proguard", "program-base", and "5.0" if all I have is a url of the form specified in the above example?

Thank you in advance, and happy holidays if this is your holiday season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're pulling the jar from a url, it doesn't matter what you call it--preferably something informative. sbt uses the organization/artifact/version to resolve dependencies from a repository. If you're providing an exact url, then it doesn't really matter.

For example, I can resolve joda-time like this, and it works just fine:

```
libraryDependencies += "doesn't" % "matter" % "2.1" from "http://central.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.jar"
```

It also uses the organization/artifact/version combination to store the jar in a specific directory in your local ivy repository. The above line downloaded the jar to:

```
~/.ivy2/cache/doesn't/matter/jars/matter-2.1.jar
```